# How to call a module method from back office specifically from order page

Tags: prestashop-1.7, prestashop-modules

I have created a module in Prestashop 1.7

I want to call the module method from back office order page.

I am overriding the order page view to create url.

what should be the URL format

I have tried so far:

```
{url entity='module' name='mymodule' controller='mymodulecontroller' params=['order_id' => $order->id]}
```

it gives a link like:

```
http://localhost/ps17/module/mymodule/mymodulecontroller?order_id=4
```

I want to return a value when this method is called.

Don't want to assign anything to JS.

This module has no configure page.

Can someone shed some light please. I know my question not very clear. I can clarify upon your question.

I have only these files
MyModule.php
Controller/Admin/MymoduleController.php
Override/..............

Modules gets installed.
Override didn't work, has to manually override.
Challenge is calling a method of  MyModule.php or Controller/Admin/MymoduleController.php using url.

Thank You!

Answer (score 1):

Prestashop has lots of Hooks. You have to use them in your module and also don't need any override.

1- Register your module in some of the Hooks during the installation process

```
$this->registerHook('displayAdminOrder')
```

2- Run your codes in the Hook method in your module

```
public function HookDisplayAdminOrder($params)
{
    // some of the codes to display something in display Hooks
    // Or some of the codes to do something in action Hooks
}
```

Some of the important Hooks in admin order page:

- actionOrderStatusPostUpdate
- displayAdminOrder
- displayAdminOrderTabContent
- displayAdminOrderContentOrder
- displayAdminOrderContentShip
- displayAdminOrderLeft
- displayAdminOrderRight
  Full list: [List of Hooks PS1.7](https://devdocs.prestashop.com/1.7/modules/concepts/hooks/list-of-hooks/)

Comment: Thank You. Suppose I have added the HookDisplayAdminOrder to the module which I have done. I am wondering how can I call that from a click of a button. I have overridden the order admin template. Is there any better way.

Comment: You can display anything using the Hooks. Just return what you want in the Hook's method.

Comment: I have registered a hook "actionGetAdminOrderButtons", checked and it is hooked. I have tried to add a button as you know. I am returning some html(for the button) but it is not working.

Comment: You can use this PrestaShop module as a guide: https://github.com/PrestaShop/example-modules/tree/master/demovieworderhooks